# Searching emails in gmail based on time

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, gmail-imap

I want a list of all yesterday's emails from gmail. I am trying to process it using google apps script, by writing a query on my inbox, and then using GmailApp.search. The after: and before: search query in gmail returns results that are not expected, since the query searches on the basis of the SMTP server time that the mail is sent from (which is google's server). Hence, being in a different time zone, the search yields inappropriate results to me. Is there a way to search gmail using a time criteria, so that I can accommodate for the time zone difference?

Please note that the local time zone, calendar, gmail etc. is correctly configured for my timezone, so the emails that I see in my inbox are correctly timed. Only the search is creating an issue.

Comment: Can you explain on a sample what are your expectations. According to the [documentation](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190) the `before:` and `after:` operators work with date (year/month/day) and not time. i.e. without taking into an account timezones.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and hence I am unable to figure out a way to get exactly last days emails according to my timezone. For example, if its 5th September today, I want all emails from 4th Sept 00:00:00 to 5th Sept 00:00:00 according to my local timezone. Example: after:2012/09/04 before:2012/09/05 search in gmail gives me some mails of 4th and some of 5th, ideally I wish to get all emails of 4th. Please note I am 12:30 hours ahead of gmail mailstore timezone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured out a way after some trial and error, that it is indeed possible to search gmail emails by time. Notice that the `Date()` returned in google apps script is according **to your timezone**.

The code below will return all previous day's emails in inbox, assuming `new Date()` is giving the date and time according to your timezone. Division by 1000 is done because `getTime()` returns milliseconds, while the newer / older search query expects seconds.

```
var month = new Date().getMonth();
var date = new Date().getDate();
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var time1 = new Date(year, month, date, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
var time2 = time1 - 86400000;
var query = "newer:" + time2/1000 + " older:"  + time1/1000 + " in:inbox";
var conversations = GmailApp.search(query);
```

Comment: Never would've figured this out. Thanks! Thought there would be a way to be more precise than by days.

Answer (score 2):

Can you give the exact search string you are using along with how you construct the before and after dates ? 
You can use  the Utilities.formatDate() function to format the date string to the timezone you are in.

An alternate solution is to fetch all mails (maybe a 100 or so) and then discard all those which do not fit in the time period you are interested in.

Comment: The datestring does not help because the output format is a date after all, and behaves the same way as a standard after: and before: search. I intend to do something like this in google apps script: query = "after:" + startTime + "before: " + endTime + " in:inobx" and the use GmailApp.search function with this query. And yeah, I have already thought of the idea of fetching all emails, and discarding some, but I am searching if a better solution is available.