# How can I analyze my Gmail History for Most Emailed?

Tags: count, gmail, gmail-api

Besides this nifty tool i found : https://immersion.media.mit.edu/

Is there any other tool/google script that can simply tell me a list of the top most emails sent ( ideally with date filters and in a spreadsheet format ) ?

the issue with Immersion is it wont show me a Subject line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any tools for your specific problem, but you could write a script and connect to a google spreadsheet on google drive - [Google's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#get_started) (i.e. make your own tool). This would be particularly useful if you want the results formatted as a spreadsheet.

Once you've figured out how to write a google script, you can use the global variable [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) to query your emails and iterate through the results like so:

```
function myFunction() {
  var maxResults = 200; // the number of results the seach gives at a time
  var query = "from: Joe"; // the same as a search query you would type into the gmail ui
  var count = 0; // the index of the last searched email
  var threads;

  do {
    threads = GmailApp.search(query, count, maxResults);

    /* you can manipulate threads here */

    count += threads.length;
  }
  while (threads.length === maxResults); // when the results are no longer full you've counted them all
}
```

Or if the total number of results isn't expected to be very large, you can just directly call: `GmailApp.search(query);`

Depend heavily on the query to tailor your results because the script can get very slow if you need to make a lot of calls to `thread.getMessages()` to check stuff. Google's search query can do it all much faster.

Here's how you can make a [gmail query based on the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261785/searching-emails-in-gmail-based-on-time?rq=1).